# Access denied office 365 / SharePoint online with Global Admin account

Tags: sharepoint, office365, csom, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-clientobject

I am going crazy since two days solving an issue. The problem is;

I am making a console APP which is talking to SharePoint Online using global admin account (One which was specified as admin while making a new subscription). What I am trying to achieve is, I want to add a custom action using CSOM to each site collection and subsite of office 365. That code works fine except on the root site collection which is pre-created by office 365 while signing up (i.e. https://xyz.sharepoint.com)

For any tenant for root site collection, it gives me below error;

> {
>   "SchemaVersion":"15.0.0.0","LibraryVersion":"16.0.3912.1201","ErrorInfo":{
>   "ErrorMessage":"Access denied. You do not have permission to perform
>   this action or access this
>   resource.","ErrorValue":null,"TraceCorrelationId":"2a47fd9c-c07b-1000-cfb7-cdffbe3ab83a","ErrorCode":-2147024891,"ErrorTypeName":"System.UnauthorizedAccessException"
>   },"TraceCorrelationId":"2a47fd9c-c07b-1000-cfb7-cdffbe3ab83a" }

Now the user is global admin. I also added again that user as site collection admin.

The same piece of code works fine on other site collections (search site collection, any newly made site collection...).

here is a code;

```
        using (ClientContext spcollContext = new ClientContext(web.Url))
        {
            SecureString passWord = new SecureString();
            foreach (char c in strAdminPassword.ToCharArray()) passWord.AppendChar(c);
            SharePointOnlineCredentials creds = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(strAdminUser, passWord);
            spcollContext.Credentials = creds;
            Web currentweb = spcollContext.Web;
            spcollContext.Load(currentweb);
            spcollContext.ExecuteQuery();

       //     authCookie = creds.GetAuthenticationCookie(new Uri(web.Url));

            var existingActions2 = currentweb.UserCustomActions;
            spcollContext.Load(existingActions2);
            spcollContext.ExecuteQuery();
            var actions2 = existingActions2.ToArray();
            foreach (var action in actions2)
            {
                if (action.Description == "CustomScriptCodeForEachsite" &&
                    action.Location == "ScriptLink")
                {
                    action.DeleteObject();
                    spcollContext.ExecuteQuery();
                }
            }

            var newAction2 = existingActions2.Add();
            newAction2.Description = "CustomScriptCodeForEachsite";
            newAction2.Location = "ScriptLink";

            newAction2.ScriptBlock = scriptBlock;
            newAction2.Update();
            spcollContext.Load(currentweb, s => s.UserCustomActions);
            spcollContext.ExecuteQuery(); // GETTING ERROR ON THIS LINE. 
        }
```

Note: Above error is Fiddler traces.

Comment: can you go and track down the rest of the error message based on the `TraceCorrelationId` from the UnauthorizedException.  It's in the exception details: "2a47fd9c-c07b-1000-cfb7-cdffbe3ab83a"

Comment: For this I can ask to MS Online team. Let me ask them in parallel. Thanks!

Comment: they've always helped with my dev issues when they've come up.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Most probably this behavior is caused by [Custom Script feature](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Turn-scripting-capabilities-on-or-off-1f2c515f-5d7e-448a-9fd7-835da935584f?ui=en-US&=amp&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1), basically
the issue occurs when the *Custom Script feature* is **turned off**

**How to verify?**

You could verify the site permissions using the following console app:

```
using (var ctx = GetContext(webUri, userName, password))
{
    var rootWeb = ctx.Site.RootWeb;
    ctx.Load(rootWeb, w => w.EffectiveBasePermissions);
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();
    var permissions = rootWeb.EffectiveBasePermissions;
    foreach (var permission in Enum.GetValues(typeof(PermissionKind)).Cast<PermissionKind>())
    {
        var permissionName = Enum.GetName(typeof(PermissionKind), permission);
        var hasPermission = permissions.Has(permission);
        Console.WriteLine("Permission: {0}, HasPermission: {1}", permissionName, hasPermission);
    }   
}
```

where

```
public static ClientContext GetContext(Uri webUri, string userName, string password)
{
    var securePassword = new SecureString();
    foreach (var ch in password) securePassword.AppendChar(ch);
    return new ClientContext(webUri) {Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(userName, securePassword)};
}
```

When [SP.PermissionKind.AddAndCustomizePages](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee556747%28v=office.14%29.aspx) is set to **False**, the Access denied error occurs while adding user custom action.

[image]

**Solution**

According to [Turn scripting capabilities on or off](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Turn-scripting-capabilities-on-or-off-1f2c515f-5d7e-448a-9fd7-835da935584f?ui=en-US&=amp&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1):

> For self-service created sites, custom scripting is disabled by
>   default

```
Solution: enable Allow users to run custom scripts on self-service created sites
```

To enable or disable scripting from the SharePoint admin center

1. Sign in to Office 365 with your work or school account.
2. Go to the SharePoint admin center.
3. Select Settings.
4. Under Custom Script choose:

   - Prevent users from running custom script on personal sites or Allow
     users to run custom script on personal sites.
   - Prevent users from running custom script on user created sites or
     Allow users to run custom script on self-service created sites.

   [image]
5. Select OK. It takes **about 24 hours** for the change to take
   effect.

---

Since any change to the scripting setting made through the SharePoint Online admin center may take up to **24 hours** to take effect, you could enable scripting on a particular site collection **immediately** via CSOM API ([SharePoint Online Client Components SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42038)) as demonstrated below:

```
public static void DisableDenyAddAndCustomizePages(ClientContext ctx, string siteUrl)
{
    var tenant = new Tenant(ctx);
    var siteProperties = tenant.GetSitePropertiesByUrl(siteUrl, true);
    ctx.Load(siteProperties);
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();

    siteProperties.DenyAddAndCustomizePages = DenyAddAndCustomizePagesStatus.Disabled;
    var result = siteProperties.Update();
    ctx.Load(result);
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();
    while (!result.IsComplete)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(result.PollingInterval);
        ctx.Load(result);
        ctx.ExecuteQuery();
    }
}
```

Usage

```
using (var ctx = GetContext(webUri, userName, password))
{
    using (var tenantAdminCtx = GetContext(tenantAdminUri, userName, password))
    {                  
         DisableDenyAddAndCustomizePages(tenantAdminCtx,webUri.ToString());
    }
    RegisterJQueryLibrary(ctx);
 }
```

where

```
public static void RegisterJQueryLibrary(ClientContext context)
{
    var actions = context.Site.UserCustomActions;
    var action = actions.Add();
    action.Location = "ScriptLink";
    action.ScriptSrc = "~SiteCollection/Style Library/Scripts/jQuery/jquery.min.js";
    action.Sequence = 1482;
    action.Update();
    context.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

Comment: Excellent answer! Yes thats the issue mate. Any way I can enable it using c#? I saw https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.online.sharepoint.tenantadministration.siteproperties.denyaddandcustomizepages(v=office.15).aspx it says that there is a property. How can I enable it using code?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have time for CSOM as described by Vadim, the page also links to a powershell script you can use:

```
Set-SPOsite <SiteURL> -DenyAddAndCustomizePages 0
```

But note that `SiteUrl` needs to be the admin url. If your tenant is https://mysite.sharepoint.com, the url you use is https://mysite-admin.sharepoint.com"

In our case, we were in the midst of a deployment when this hit and could not wait 24 hours (or even one hour!) to continue. Everything had been fine in our testing site collections, but when we deployed to the tenant root, we hit the error described above and this script fixed it. Apparently the feature is turned off by default on the tenant root.

[Current site is not a tenant administration site](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/msonline/en-US/df263536-a7b7-4c79-afd4-98f4b30ad788/current-site-is-not-a-tenant-administration-site?forum=onlineservicessharepoint)

[Turn scripting capabilities on or off](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Turn-scripting-capabilities-on-or-off-1f2c515f-5d7e-448a-9fd7-835da935584f?ui=en-US&=amp&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1)

Answer (score 0):

My first response would be that you shouldn't add a `CustomAction` on the fly through code.  That said, I'm sure you have a good reason to need to do so.

Try to set the `AllowUnsafeUpdates` flag on `SPWeb` to `true` as soon as you reference `currentWeb`.  Make sure to also set it back to `false` after you call the final `ExecuteQuery()`

By default, `AllowUnsafeUpdates` is `false`.  It is used to block cross-site scripting attacks.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb_properties.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the update GlennFerrie, however AllowUpsafeUpdates is a full trust code and not part of CSOM. I am asking a question for sharepoint ONLINE and CSOM.

Comment: Also the main thing is the SAME code works for other site collections. If it would have been problem like this, then error would have been consistent for all sites.