# Sharepoint Rest Api calls`

Tags: javascript, html, rest, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am making a simple website where I have to save some of my data to sharepoint list. I am using only html css js only. I need to make REST calls to Sharepoint APIs to post data on SP. I am trying to get data from my list(in SP) as follow:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        processListItems(hostweburl, 'ListName');
    });

function processListItems(url, listname) {

        $.ajax({
            url: url + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listname + "')",
            method: "GET",
            headers: {
                "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"
            },
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);      
            },
            error: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    }
```

It returns this response:

```
"{"error":{"code":"-2147024891, System.UnauthorizedAccessException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource."}}}"
```

I am referencing only two scripts:

```
 <script src="js/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/4.0/1/MicrosoftAjax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

It says I am unauthorised to access. Although I am having admin rights to my list. Please tell me how to fix this issue. Do I need any authorization header for ajax call to Rest Api? I am new to Sharepoint. Please Help!

Comment: Is it on premise or SharePoint Online? Maybe this can help you https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/e9924aef-28df-43a4-8d79-a9d1532699c6/systemunauthorizedaccessexception-when-accessing-sharepoint-2013-rest-api?forum=sharepointsearch.
Also this: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/187926/system-unauthorizedaccessexception-when-accessing-the-sharepoint-2013-rest-api

Comment: Sharepoint Online

Comment: i am creating this using js html only

Comment: links are not helping

Comment: It seems to be a permission problem, make sure that you have read/full control rights on the web as well, not only on the list.

Comment: What you mean by "creating this using js html only" where your JS code running... ? Are you hosting code in SharePoint itself?

Comment: No i am not hosting it in sharepoint it is separate

Comment: If i am using on premise SP then how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

I think that custom scripting is disabled by default in SPOnline.  You may have to enable it.  These links may help:

[Access denied office 365 / SharePoint online with Global Admin account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29675567/access-denied-office-365-sharepoint-online-with-global-admin-account)

http://vamsi-sharepointhandbook.blogspot.com/2015/07/turn-scripting-capabilities-on-or-off.html

Comment: DO I need any access token for it.

Comment: for Restful api calls

Comment: Can I pass username and password as a part of ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

When you are trying to pull items from a list, specify the URL up to items. See below line for syntax -

```
$.ajax({
url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('"+listName+"')/items",
// Rest of the code
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you would need a authorization header for your requests. So your headers should be like this:

```
headers: {
             "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose",
             "Authorization": 'Bearer '+ **access_token**   
         }
```

access_token: You would need to acquire access token to make requests. You can use [adal library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-authentication-libraries) provided by Microsoft for that.